# Graceful shutdown with spring and long-running threads

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, long-running-processes, graceful-shutdown

We have the problem that there are multiple async threads that process a bunch of data and need minutes or some of them even hours to end. The pod also processes some other short running request.

It might occur that the pod has to be moved, and a shutdown will happen during this processing. In this case, we want the threads to finish their work in short term and leave a status, which we can use to process the remaining data.

We already use `graceful.shutdown=enable`.

The idea now is that we introduce a method with `@PreDestroy` in the bean that creates the async threads.
When this method is called, it will set a "shutdown" flag in a different bean. All the long-running threads check this flag during processing and will stop processing when it's true and write a clean state of their processing to the database.

This is more or less working ... but not all the time.

As I understood after getting the shutdown trigger at first, there is a configurable time `spring.lifecycle.timeout-per-shutdown-phase` where threads can continue processing their work without reduction in any of the needed resources. After the time is over, all the shutdownhooks are processed in an unknown order. This brings me to the thought that I might not have all the necessary resources for leaving a clean state, when I use the approach with the `@preDestroy` and the flag.

Is there a better solution to this?

Is there a need to add some more configuration to the threads like    `setAwaitTerminationSeconds(60);` or `setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);`?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Have you thought about breaking "bunch of data" to be processed by longer running threads to smaller chunks that could be done quicker? If necessary an intermediate status could be saved to a db to picked up by the next thread. Shorter running threads already work, why not designing the work load such that all threads are short lived?

Answer (score 0):

What I found is, when using `graceful.shutdown=enable` and `@PreDestroy` in spring, that you need to `synchronize` the `run()` method and the `@PreDestroy` method (provided that both are in the same class):

```java
@Service
public class MyClass implements Runnable {
  private volatile boolean shutDown = false;
  public MyClass( TaskScheduler taskScheduler) {
        taskScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this, 100);
  }
  @PreDestroy
    public synchronized void preDestroy() {
        this.shutDown = true;
        log.info("@PreDestroy Callback triggered for shutting down");
    }
 @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        if (this.shutDown) {
            this.shutdownCounter++;
            return;
        }
        // put in here, whatever you long running task needs to do
    }
```

And you need to make sure, that your `run()` method is not doing anything, when `preDestroy()` was already called, hence the `shutdown`- flag.

What the `synchronize` does is, that  `preDestroy()` automatically waits until `run()` is finished regularly. Only then `preDestroy()` is called, and by setting the `shutDown` flag, it prevents that it starts another long running thread, even in case `run()` is called again. Instead `run()` returns immediately.

Because otherwise, when you don't synchronized, then the `preDestroy()` is called immediately after the spring - server get a `shutdown` signal but spring `thinks` if `preDestroy()` has run and finished successful, that it can shut down  itself immediately. Which is not what you want, because then all `run()` threads gets interrupted.

I also found, that this example above does **not** work when using the `@Scheduled`- annotation (instead of calling `taskScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this, 100)` in the constructor)